# checkScreenSharingCapability in Chrome 76 returns extensionRequired: "chrome"

Tags: opentok, tokbox

The TokBox documentation is confusing because it clearly states:

```
Important: As of Chrome 72+ and Firefox 52+, an extension is no longer needed for screen sharing. The browser prompts the end user for access to the screen as it would for access to the camera.
```

However, the sample code has:

```
OT.checkScreenSharingCapability(function(response) {
  if(!response.supported || response.extensionRegistered === false) {
    // This browser does not support screen sharing
  }
});
```

And chrome version 76 returns:

```
extensionInstalled: false
extensionRegistered: false
extensionRequired: "chrome"
supported: true
```

So Chrome 76 will say it's unsupported.  Firefox v68 returns extensionRegistered = undefined so it passes.  If I ignore the error and try to do screensharing in Chrome anyway, it fails and says the extension is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating @opentok/client from 2.15.1 to 2.16.2